# MySQL: How to count a record's matching conditions, select and order by it

Tags: mysql

To select post IDs and order them by the amount of matched conditions in the where statement I'm using the following (not-specificly-WordPress) query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ID,
  -- @matches -- Not to be selected in the final query
FROM
  (SELECT @matches := 0) dummy_table, -- Declare user var within a single query
  wp_posts p
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON (p.ID = tr.object_id)
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id)
INNER JOIN wp_terms t ON (t.term_id = tt.term_id)
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND ( @matches := 0 ) IS NOT NULL -- Reset counting var. Returns true for this condition
  AND (
       -- START comparing and counting matches
       ( tt.taxonomy = 'tags'
         AND t.term_id IN (110, 84) -- Post has a matching tag
         AND (@matches := @matches + 1) -- Increment counter. Returns false
       )
       OR 
       ( tt.taxonomy = 'other-taxonomy'
         AND t.term_id IN (333, 330, 331) -- Post has a matching 'other-taxonomy' term
         AND (@matches := @matches + 1) -- Increment counter. Returns false
       )
       -- OR [... more of the same ...]
       -- END comparing and counting matches
       OR 1 = 1 -- Always return true for this OR-condition
      )
  AND ( 0 < @matches ) -- Only select with matches
ORDER BY 
  @matches DESC, RAND();" -- Order with match priority, then randomly
```

The idea is this: I'd like to select all posts that match either one of the taxonomy terms I defined, hence the `OR` conditions. But since I'd like to order the posts by the amount of matches, I need to both count all matched conditions as well as force the `OR` condition to check for every match evaluation. The per-match variable calculation is supposed to invalidate the `AND` condition and thus forces the `OR` condition to iterate further.
Finally, the counter is used to select the post when any match was found as well as order the posts according to the amount of matches.

Yet, the query results in 0 selections, though there really are posts in my DB that have a matching term. The variable usage and calculations are setup as per http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/15/advanced-mysql-user-variable-techniques/. When I remove the `OR 1 = 1`, posts are found, but the counter seems not to be reset (matches are 2,4,6,8...).

The question is: how do I solve this situation? How can I effectively count a post's matching conditions and both select and order by them, within the single query?